# Best ruby rest framework like python Flask-RESTful?

Tags: python, ruby, api, rest

I need to create API for my project and learn Ruby by the way. Earlier I created APIs in Flask-RESTful and I looking for something simple as Flask-RESTful for Ruby.

I'm just started with Ruby so I have no knowledge what would be the best.

Flask-RESTful allows you to do many things automatically and creating useful, small API takes 15 minutes and 50 lines of code. I'll find something similar for Ruby ?

Or maybe I should guided by other criteria ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's a Ruby framework quite similar to Flask.